# Hide Smart card content

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare

I have one stupid question. I have mifare classic tags (1k). I want to hide content of this card (any data stored there). How to do it? 
What about ndef records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC (MiFare Classic) got reverse engineered completely, so storage should be considered read-write, and clear text, copiable/clonable, etc.

If you can afford encryption of the payload before putting it on the card, you may be able to make data confidential, but not "hide" it: third parties will be able to tell card is not blank, but will not be able to tell what is actually stored.

NDEF wont help you there.

Comment: I know that Mifare Classic is not secure, but I saw some cards with this standard, which was "blank" for some android NFC applications. But I know there were stored data.
Data encryption was first thing which I made with this, but I also want to make it a little more safe.

Comment: "blank" in this context is whatever the app provider means of it. It could mean "unknow the payload format", "not NDEF", "No MAD found" (mifare application directory), or even "unknown keys", because even if MFC is broken, phone apps usually dont try to crack sector keys.

Answer (score 1):

MIFARE Classic allows to store data in sectors, which can be access protected. So authentication with the sector key needs to be done before any read operation (if configured that way).
"Generic" apps like NFC TagInfo usually try out "well-known" keys, before declaring a sector content "unknown". They don't try to hack the keys.
You can also use more advanced products, like MIFARE Plus or MIFARE DESFire, which both use AES cryptography for authentication and data encryption.